# jQuery scrollTo works in Chrome but not FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, scroll

Alright, so I have a `scrollTo` function as follows:

```
$.fn.scrollTo = function(t, d, o)
    {
        var scrollTarget = t;
        var offsetTop = (typeof(o) != 'undefined') ? o : Math.floor((window.innerHeight / 2) - 20);
        var duration = (typeof(d) != 'undefined') ? d : 10;
        var easing = 'swing';
        var scrollPane = $(this);
        var scrollY = (typeof scrollTarget == "number") ? scrollTarget : scrollTarget.offset().top + scrollPane.scrollTop() - parseInt(offsetTop);
        scrollPane.animate({scrollTop : scrollY }, parseInt(duration), easing, function()
        {
            if (typeof callback == 'function')
                callback.call(this);
        });
    }
```

I call it via `$("body").scrollTo($obj, 10);`

It works flawlessly in Chrome, but nothing happens in Firefox.

`scrollTo` and `scrollPane.animate` both get called, but nothing happens. No errors either, and all the values look right - it just doesn't scroll.

It's only being called once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the top level page element that scrolls is inconsistent among browsers. Some browsers like Firfox require the `html` tag be scrolled, while WebKit based browsers like Chrome require the `body` element be scrolled. The easiest solution is to apply it to both elements like so.

```
$("html, body").scrollTo($obj, 10);
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/51ae1tnf/)**